# How do I display validation errors in Rails 3? 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have the following code:

```
validates :username,:password, :presence => {:message => 'fields must not be blank'}
```

but I can't get the error message when the field is blank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access them through the errors array:

```
<model_instance>.errors
```

You can then access the messages individually by doing:

```
model.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
  puts message
end
```

Answer (score 1):

for example

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.valid? 
    logger.warn("====valid==========#{@user.error.full_messages.inspect}============")        
  else
    logger.warn("====error==========#{@user.error.full_messages.inspect}============")        
  end
end
```

check in your terminal what this print

Answer (score 0):

Not sure though, but something like this worked for me (Just an example scenario):

```
def create
  model_instance = Model.new
  begin
    if model_instance.save_model # custom save for model (if required)
      # code
    else
      # code
    end
  rescue
    p model_instance.errors # here you will be able to access them.
  end
end
```

So its nothing much only exception handling is introduced.

And one more suggestion, the line of code in the question, if the **username** is blank the error message will be **"Username fields must not be blank"**, so its suggested to have singular error messages :)

Hope it'l help !!